# Mysql ignoring where?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following which seems to ignore "list.Completed". It still displays results marked with a 1. Removing everything after AND makes it work fine but I need to only have results where both columns do not show null.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
list.WorkOrder,
list.Address,
emails.MailDate,
locateparsed.WorkDate,
list.Completed
FROM list
LEFT JOIN parsed ON parsed.WorkOrder = list.WorkOrder
LEFT JOIN emails ON emails.EmailID = parsed.OriginID
LEFT JOIN locateparsed ON list.WorkOrder = locateparsed.WorkOrder
WHERE list.Completed = '0' AND emails.MailDate IS NOT NULL OR locateparsed.WorkDate IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some parentheses:

```
WHERE list.Completed = '0' AND (emails.MailDate IS NOT NULL OR locateparsed.WorkDate IS NOT NULL)
```

Boolean evaluation is done left-to-right, so if you want the `OR` to have priority, you'll need to do it this way.